# ReferenceError: Can't find variable in react native

Tags: react-native, razorpay

**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Razorpay**

Trying to create a Razorpay order with my key_id and key_secret in React native with the following code, but getting the above error. Clearly I have to import Razorpay from somewhere, but I'm not sure from where I need to import it.

[image]

```
var instance = new Razorpay({
                  key_id: 'MY_KEY_ID',
                  key_secret: 'MY_KEY_SECRET'
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided is taken from [**server side** node sdk](https://razorpay.com/docs/server-integration/nodejs/usage/). You should never put any secret keys in client side applications as these can easily be stolen by anyone who has your app. For react-native you need client-side sdk, read here for [iOS](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/react-native-integration/standard/ios/) and [Android](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/react-native-integration/standard/android/) installation and import instructions

Comment: Thanks, understood the issue...followed the link you shared, but what is the instance here? Do I need to define it somewhere? Actually I'm new to ReactNative and having some tough time understanding the flow here.

Comment: As seen in the docs, there is no `instance` on client side. You need both client and server-side set up in order for it to work. You need to create order on server side, take order_id and send it over to the client, then use this order_id in `option` inside RazorpayCheckout.open(options) @SandipBiswas

Comment: The clarification was quite helpful!! @Max